# Install Extension of Python in Visual studio Code in Server 2022

Tags: python, multiple-users, windows-server-2022

I have a Windows Server 2019 at a school that uses Visual Studio Code. The application installs for all users without a problem, but I can't seem to get the Python extension for this application to install for all users who connect. They have to install it one by one, and this is not advisable. I can't find a way to do a global installation of the extension. Thank you very much. –

I Want to install for all the users.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.